# How long can a newborn girl bleed from her vagina?

Tags: newborn, health

The bleeding from a newborn girl's vagina is completely normal, it happens due to hormones being absorbed by the baby while still in the womb.

How long can this bleeding last?

Does it come and go, or does it occur only once for a period of time?

Today morning during diaper change of our 12 day old we have noticed some blood and mucus coming from her vagina, and of course have cleaned it. During next diaper change (2 hours later) there was even more blood - even more than during the first few days after her birth when she also bled. Should we be worried?

*Update:*

*My daughter is almost a year old now and we had no further problems. We've also then consulted with a pediatrician, she said it is rare (the blood appearing, disappearing and appearing again), but it happens. And unless there was a relatively large amount of blood (a major leak instead of a droplet) we sholdn't worry.*

Comment: My baby five days old I was really concerned I damnnear panic. But once I talked to the doctor they said it was normal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Baby Center says if you still see some after six weeks mention it to your doc at your post-natal check.  Even with real menstruation there can be a bit of an "ebb and flow" to it.  The fact that it wasn't there and then was probably doesn't mean anything.  In my experience it was only the first few days, but it probably greatly depends on how the birth occured/length of time etc.  If you see a lot of blood or if it is gone for more than a week or two and then comes back I'd mention it to doc though.

http://www.babycentre.co.uk/a115/caring-for-your-babys-genitals

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the question. How about that bleeding happening once and then coming back?

Comment: I think that is also fairly normal - but you could mention it to your pediatrician jsut to be sure and ease your mind.

Answer (score 1):

Its  normal I guess, but still to be on safe side, I would recommend you take/show your daughter to the HV/ Doctor.
One of my twins had a milky white discharge from her vagina two days after birth. I panicked and took her to the doctor, who said not to worry. Only if there is a foul smell coming from the discharge; then there may be an infection.
As you said, its all due to hormones.
Bleeding after birth or few days after is okay.
What I want to know is:
If it is just a few drops or heavy bleeding. If its the former,then its perfectly normal.

Dont worry. It will stop eventually. 
While cleaning her vagina, just spread the labia a bit and gently clean the creases with luke warm water and no need to dig deeper as it may hurt the baby.